# LazyLoading angular directives

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I have an issue while lazy loading a simple directive with [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad). The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController">
        <say-hello to="world"></say-hello>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module("LazyLoadTest", [ "oc.lazyLoad"])
            .controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad){
                $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: "testApp",
                        files: ["testApp.js"],
                        serie: true
                    }).then(function () {
                        var el = angular.element('#example');
                        el.append('<say-hello to="world"></say-hello>');
                    }, function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With testApp.js beeing:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("testApp", []).directive("sayHello", function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                to: '@to'
            },
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<p>Hello {{to}}</>'
        };
    });
})();
```

The directive, that works when used without lazy loading, does not display anything. As you see I have the directive once in the DOM from the beginning, of course angularJS will not recognize the directive as the module is not lazy loaded yet and later I add it with the angular append function. I thought that ocLazyLoad would bootstrap the app with the new modules and therefore that the directives would be resolved. But this seems not to be the case. How can I get the directives to work with lazy loading in this example.

I have also created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3PPjtXXQUCUsbLkpguN3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I have to compile the element before I append. See the following working code where the compile function runs when the promise is resolved:

```
    angular.module("LazyLoadTest", [ "oc.lazyLoad"])
        .controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $compile){
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: "testApp",
                    files: ["testApp.js"],
                    serie: true
                }).then(function () {
                    var el, elToAppend;
                    elToAppend = $compile('<say-hello to="world"></say-hello>')( $scope );
                    el = angular.element('#example');
                    el.append(elToAppend);
                }, function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                })
    });
```